# Hide many divs with on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 6divs and i want on button click to hide five and show one, on  other button click to hide five others and show one.
I don't want to hide all them one by one. Is any way to hide all by ID in the same time:
My html code:

```
<div id="ad1" style="display: none;">Div content 1</div>
<div id="ad2" style="display: none;">Div content 2</div>
<div id="ad3" style="display: none;">Div content 3</div>
<div id="ad4" style="display: none;">Div content 4</div>
<div id="ad5" style="display: none;">Div content 5</div>
<br/>
<button id='button1'>click1</button>
<button id='button2'>click2</button>
<button id='button3'>click3</button>
<button id='button4'>click4</button>
<button id='button5'>click5</button>
```

I tried something like this:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $("#ad1").show();
    $("#ad2 #ad3 #ad4 #ad5").hide();
});

$("#button2").click(function () {
    $("#ad2").show();
    $("#ad1 #ad3 #ad4 #ad5").hide();
});
```

My jsfiddle : [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/egzontina/wqL1qdho/2/)

Any help :)

Comment: $("#ad2, #ad3, #ad4, #ad5")

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Comment: Please see that we are not here to code for you. It would be great if you could read the API docs and if the problem still persists then you ask questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just separate the elements with `,` to select multiple elements:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    $("#ad1").show();
    $("#ad2, #ad3, #ad4, #ad5").hide();
});

$("#button2").click(function () {
    $("#ad2").show();
    $("#ad1, #ad3, #ad4, #ad5").hide();
});
```

Here is your updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wqL1qdho/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#button1").click(function () {
    visible =  $(".ads:visible");
    next = visible.next(".ads");
    debugger;
    if(next.length > 0 ){
     next.show();
    }else{
    $(".ads").first().show();
    }
    visible.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ads" id="ad1">Div content 1</div>
<div class="ads" id="ad2" style="display: none;">Div content 2</div>
<div class="ads" id="ad3" style="display: none;">Div content 3</div>
<div class="ads" id="ad4" style="display: none;">Div content 4</div>
<div class="ads" id="ad5" style="display: none;">Div content 5</div>
<br/>
<button id='button1'>click1</button>
```